# Bottom-up parsing with boost-spirit

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit

I wanted to create a rule in boost::spirit::qi that does [bottom-up parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom-up_parsing).
I have this data structure:

```
struct Bnop;
typedef boost::variant<int,boost::recursive_wrapper<Bnop> > Expr;
struct Bnop { char op; Expr left, right; };
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT ( Bnop, (Expr, left) (char, op) (Expr, right))
```

And with these rules:

```
    qi::rule<Iter,Expr(),ns::space_type> ex;
    qi::rule<Iter,Bnop(),ns::space_type> bin;
    ex = bin | qi::int_;
    bin = qi::int_ >> ns::char_ >> ex;
```

The string "1+2+3+4+5" is parsed into a structure that "looks like" (1+(2+(3+(4+5))))
Basically, what I wanted to achieve is ((((1+2)+3)+4)+5)

After some struggle I've actually made a working solution. The rules are:

```
    qi::rule<Iter,Expr(),qi::locals<int>,ns::space_type> expr;
    qi::rule<Iter,Expr(Expr),qi::locals<char,int>,ns::space_type> rhs;
    expr =  omit[ int_[_a=_1]] >> rhs(_a);
    rhs  =  omit[char_[_a=_1]] >> 
            omit[ int_[_b=_1]] >> 
            rhs(construct<Bnop>(_r1,_a,_b)) 
         |  attr(_r1);
```

Two things do still bother me, though:

1. It looks a bit complex and cluttered. Maybe there is a more compact/elegant way of doing that?
2. Also I worried about the efficiency of that approach. Does the use of inherited attributes, locals  and, especially, phoenix::construct, somehow affect the productivity of spirit?

---

The full code is [here](http://pastebin.com/bdqGuDyS)